# Want to collect only one user with current result....in linq

Tags: asp.net, linq

I want to collect distinct user from message table. I written query but getting all message with user. Following are the code

```
   public IList<Entities.ent_Message.messageDetails> messages(decimal userNumber)
    {   
        owncibai_ExamEntities db = new owncibai_ExamEntities();
        var messages = db.Messages.Where(wh => wh.messageTo == userNumber).OrderByDescending(or => or.mDate).Select(a => new Entities.ent_Message.messageDetails
         {
             message = a.Message1.Substring(0, 50) + "...",
             messageID = a.messID,
             Name = a.User.First_Name + " " + a.User.Last_Name,
             photo = a.User.imagePath,
             userNumber = (long)a.userNumber,
             myDate = a.mDate,
             isRead = (bool)(a.isRead == null ? false : a.isRead == false ? false : true)
         }).ToList();

         return messages;
    }
```

But and the result is as follows. In left pane two similar rows is appearing. I tried with group but also did not work.
Result is as follows

User 1
   Message abcd
User 1
    message xyz
...
...

While I want result as
User 1                        ---    Message1
     Latest Mesage xyz        ----   Message 2

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you clarify your question a little bit? Are you just expecting one row back? I'm having a hard time understanding the difference between the results you have and the results you want.

Comment: Why don't you query `user.Messages`?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your question, but I think you're trying to say you want one row with the most recent message in it. In this case, you don't need to be returning a list at all, and you need to take advantage of the FirstOrDefault() function to make sure you only grab the first record (or null if none exist).

```
public Entities.ent_Message.messageDetails messages(decimal userNumber)
{   
    owncibai_ExamEntities db = new owncibai_ExamEntities();
    var message = db.Messages.Where(wh => wh.messageTo == userNumber).OrderByDescending(or => or.mDate).Select(a => new Entities.ent_Message.messageDetails
     {
         message = a.Message1.Substring(0, 50) + "...",
         messageID = a.messID,
         Name = a.User.First_Name + " " + a.User.Last_Name,
         photo = a.User.imagePath,
         userNumber = (long)a.userNumber,
         myDate = a.mDate,
         isRead = (bool)(a.isRead == null ? false : a.isRead == false ? false : true)
     }).FirstOrDefault();

     return message;
}
```

Does this get you what you need?

Comment: Hi smelch  Thanks fore reply....
Actually I want similar facebook message system... in which unique user left side ... while all conversation between current user and unique on right side.
But in my case left side all same user repeated with number of message ...